# Different prototyping with typedef and #define

Tags: c++, c, linked-list, typedef, c-preprocessor

I'm writing a set of linked lists functions for a project.
I need to provide flexibility as for the data type in the list nodes (int/char)

So I'm trying to do something like so:

**in main.cpp**

```
#define INT_DATA
#include "lists.h"
....
```

**in lists.h**

```
#ifdef CHAR_DATA
typedef char DATA_TYPE;
#endif
#ifdef INT_DATA
typedef int DATA_TYPE;
#endif

typedef struct lnode {
    DATA_TYPE data;
    struct lnode* next; //points to the next node
} LNODE;

LNODE * createNewListNode(DATA_TYPE data, LNODE* next);
....
```

but all of this doesn't seem to work...
I don't want to have to write duplicate code when just the prototypes are different..

What am I doing wrong? Is this possible?

**PLEASE NOTE**

This is an exercise, I can't use classes, I can't use any standard libraries

Comment: If you're using C++, then perhaps you could simply use std::list instead of writing your own?

Comment: Why use something cumbersome like the pre-processor instead of templates? Also, can you add the errors you get to your question?

Comment: That's not C++, that's C. You're not fooling anyone with that `.cpp` extension. If you want to do C++ for real, use templates.

Comment: @BenC I can't use classes, I can't use any standard libraries

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I can't use classes, I can't use any standard libraries

Comment: @Omer So? Templates aren't classes, and they aren't part of the SL.

Answer (score 9):

This is where C++'s templates enter. Templates allow you to create a skeleton of an implementation. In this case, you may want a class which takes a 'data type' as a parameter. Sounds nice… here's what it looks like:

```
template < typename DATA_TYPE >  
struct lnode {
  DATA_TYPE data;
  lnode<DATA_TYPE>* next; //points to the next node
};
```

Then you can create them like this:

```
lnode<char> charNode;
lnode<int> intNode;
```

Comment: how do I apply this when I have dozens of functions that need to be templated? is there a better approach than duplicating "template < typename DATA_TYPE >" before each prototype ?

Comment: No. If you looked at my answer, you would find two links to articles about templates. There is a way, though: put the functions as static members of some class - then you can just template the class, not every function on it's own. I wish C++ allowed templating namespaces...

Comment: @OmerCohen in that case, you might prefer to use methods and declare functions in the class body -- if that's an appropriate place for them.

Comment: @justin I can't use classes, I can't use any standard libraries

Answer (score 2):

Don't use defines. Use templates (good articles: [one](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html) and [two](http://womble.decadentplace.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html)).

Also, that `typedef struct lnode { /* ... */ } LNODE;` is just C, not even close to C++.

Comment: C++ is a superset of c.  So why act like c code is not valid c++ code?  This doesn't even address the question.  its a petty argument that provides nothing constructive.  The links on the other hand are probably where he should start.

Comment: @Dan, C++ is not a superset of C since a very long time.